# How to perform an action while a key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

How to make that when pressing a key do an action and when you press it again, stop doing it in C#.

**What I want to do:** I have a program which the user must press <kbd>F1</kbd> to activate any action, well; so that the user does not press another key, but the same one, how would this be done in C #? Since I currently stop the action by doing the following:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F1) == -32767)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F2) == -32767)
{
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

Comment: What type of application are you building? Console, WPF, Forms or UWP?

Comment: It is an application made in forms

Comment: Simplest way is to just make a boolean toggle that changes when the key has been pressed

Comment: I have tried, for example I did the following:

 bool activado;

                        activado = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F1) != 0;
                        if (activado)
                        {
                            tInitial.Start();
                        }

But I have no result yet..

Comment: Or maybe instead of `timer1.Start();` do `if(timer1.Enabled) timer1.Stop(); else timer1.Start()`

Comment: A tons of way from boolean to background worker.

Comment: bool F1Down = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F1) < 0;  Compare to a F1PreviouslyDown variable to see changes.

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49529961/edit) button to update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.Timers.Timer`.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Key.A)
    {
        if(!timer1.Enabled)
            timer1.Start();
        else
            timer1.Stop();

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I should've posted my comment as an answer ^^ take my +1

Comment: I have a question, I use GetAsyncKeyState to do the action, would it work the same way this way?

Comment: @AurelioGálvez , yes it should work as you need to manager the relative integer value for the key. Everything else will be same. This code is working one.

Comment: @Rafalon thanks buddy :)

Comment: @GaurangDave Thank you very much, it worked perfectly!

Comment: @AurelioGálvez Kindly mark as an answer / upvote if useful. Enjoy coding :)

Comment: Why downvoted? Its an accepted answer.

Comment: @GaurangDave Sorry, I still do not know very well how is this StackOverflow, I thought that if I gave to accept boto (the green button) it meant that I had served, I have already removed, sorry again.

Comment: @AurelioGálvez of course the green button means the answer solved your problem, so if it is the case, you should re-do it. What Gaurang said is that someone downvoted his answer (clicked on the "down" arrow)

Comment: I understand.. Personally, the answer helped me; I thank you very much:  @GaurangDave For your pleasant response. I differ from who was the person who gave negative feedback.